# Refresh Icon in Android View on Variable

Tags: android, button, view

I got a Button in my Main Activity which can get two background images.
I got a variable in a class, which is boolean and got the state the button should have.

In the onCreate() I got following:

```
    if(HelperFunctions.itsRinging == true){

    stopButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.klingelt);

    }else {
        stopButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
    }
```

If the App is closed, a push message comes in, I open the app, the icon got the "klingelt" background. Like it should!
After clicking it, it got the "normal" background. Like it should!

But when the app is in front, the icons not changes.
How can i refresh the background even if the app is in front?

The button itself is in a standard onClick Method:

```
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                SoundManager.stop();
                //set Background normal
                if(HelperFunctions.itsRinging = true) {
                    stopButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    HelperFunctions.itsRinging = false;
                }
```

I hope its clear, what I want to archieve here :)
So the icon should change its background in "live-mode" when the app is on in front and visible.

Comment: Did you try repainting your button ?

Comment: I tried:
            stopButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.klingelt);
            stopButton.refreshDrawableState();
and
stopButton.invalidate();

But it won't work